# How do I find the function and derivative of an unknown curve?

Tags: functions, approximation, regression, mathematical-modeling, tangent-line

I have $x$ and $y$ values to plot the curve and I need to find a tangent line of slope 1 that intersects the curve (and the point at which it intersects). I was trying to do polynomial and exponential regression to model the data and fit the curve (in R) but cannot get it to work. It fits a majority of the data but not the curve and I need the function of the curve to find the derivative and tangent.

I don't completely understand the math behind the modeling but all I know is that the fit is inaccurate when I plot it against my data. Is there any way I solve this mathematically? [The curve starts slightly downwards, then slopes up gradually before it goes up exponentially](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38bNs.png)

If you do a density plot, most of the values are towards the lower end of y. [the values of y are right skewed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7Jhm.png). This could be influencing my model, so would one solution be to remove multiple prior points?

UPDATE: I tried to limit the number of points and now my plot looks like this (the line plotted is $8.950433e^{-20}\times1.006621^x$). The formula for the line was from taking the exponential regression of the data. From the formula, it kind of makes sense why it's a line but how do I get it to curve?
[image]

Comment: Are the x-points actual values or just the numbering for the specific data point?

Comment: In general, it's not possible to deduce the actual function knowing a fixed number of points. You can use interpolation to approximate it. The tangent line can also be approximated by taking two points on the curve and drawing a line thru them. The closer the points, the better is the approximation.

Comment: @QC_QAOA the x values are just 1 to ~6600 (number of total points).

Comment: @Vasili I did try taking the slope of every three points (sliding window style), but I think the points are too close together/similar because the slope did not change much for some reason

Comment: @la.poubelle: I am surprised exponential regression model did not work for you, the graph does look like an exponential. Maybe you need to use different models on different intervals.

Comment: @Vasili I just tried that but my model still looks like a line, not a curve (see update)

Answer (score 0):

One cannot give an accurate solution without numerical data (a graph isn't enough). As a consequence the results shown below are approximates from scanning your graph https://i.stack.imgur.com/38bNs.png for appoximate data.

Certainly many convenient model equations could be proposed. For example with series of tangent function  :

[image]

As well one could propose a lot of models with series of various functions.

For example series of inverse hyperbolic tangent function :

[image]

Even simpler an example with series of hyperbolic function :

[image]

Comment : If your graph comes from actual measurements the above values of the parameters have no physical signifiance. A model derived from physical properties should be better.